# как разослать сообщения пользователям при помощи их id

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

У меня есть список id пользователей и им надо переслать текстовое сообщение но они бота не запускали у себя я пользуюсь aiogram но если у вас есть решение данной задачи на других библиотеках. Все мои решения заводили меня в тупик

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import asyncio

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import StatesGroup, State

import config

bot = Bot(token=config.BOT_TOKEN)
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)
# вы должны храить в бд или где-то еще юзер айди ваших пользователей
# к примеру пусть это будет список
list_with_users = [1234132, 341254235]


@dp.message_handler(commands=["comm"])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    for user_id in list_with_users:
        try:
            await bot.send_message(chat_id=user_id, text="text")
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
        except Exception:
            await message.answer("Ошибка отправки.")
            await asyncio.sleep(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: спасибо большое!